# How can C#'s string.IndexOf perform so fast, 10 times faster than ordinary for loop find?

Tags: c#, string, search, indexof

I have a very long string (**60MB** in size) in which I need to find how many pairs of '<' and '>' are in there.

---

I have first tried my own way:

```
        char pre = '!';
        int match1 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < html.Length; j++)
        {
            char c = html[j];
            if (pre == '<' && c == '>') //find a match
            {
                pre = '!';
                match1++;
            }
            else if (pre == '!' && c == '<')
                pre = '<';
        }
```

The above code runs on my string for roughly **1000 ms**.

---

Then I tried using `string.IndexOf`

```
        int match2 = 0;
        int index = -1;
        do
        {
            index = html.IndexOf('<', index + 1);
            if (index != -1) // find a match
            {
                index = html.IndexOf('>', index + 1);
                if (index != -1)
                   match2++;
            }
        } while (index != -1);
```

The above code runs for only around **150 ms**.

---

I am wondering what is the magic that makes `string.IndexOf` runs **so fast**?

Anyone can inspire me?

---

**Edit**

Ok, according to @BrokenGlass's answer. I modified my code in the way that they don't check the pairing, instead, they check how many '<' in the string.

---

```
        for (int j = 0; j < html.Length; j++)
        {
            char c = html[j];
            if (c == '>')
            {
                match1++;
            }
        }
```

the above code runs for around **760 ms**.

---

Using `IndexOf`

```
        int index = -1;
        do
        {
            index = html.IndexOf('<', index + 1);
            if (index != -1)
            {
                match2++;
            }
        } while (index != -1);
```

The above code runs for about **132 ms**. **still very very fast.**

---

**Edit 2**

After read @Jeffrey Sax comment, I realised that I was running in VS with Debug mode.

Then I built and ran in release mode, ok, `IndexOf` is still faster, but not that faster any more.

Here is the results:

For the pairing count: **207ms VS 144ms**

For the normal one char count: **141ms VS 111ms**.

My own codes' performance was really improved.

---

**Lesson learned: when you do the benchmark stuff, do it in release mode!**

Comment: Did you enable optimizations while testing?

Comment: Have you taken a look at what `string.IndexOf` is doing behind the scenes?

Comment: @MartinLiversage How to enable optimizations?

Comment: @zimdanen No, that's what I am asking actually

Comment: @MartinLiversage Yes, I checked and it is enabled always

Comment: Try implementing your own version of the IndexOf function that behaves the same way as the string.IndexOf, then the comparison will be more "fair" and it will be possible to argue if IndexOf does "something magical".

Comment: Try not to use html.length, try `int len =html.length;` and then use `len` in the for loop.

Comment: @HaLaBi string.Length is static, only changes or sum when string is modified. It is not a on-fly counting.

Comment: @Jack: Now you search through the full string in your implementation while you stop the search once you have found a `<` `>` pair in the `IndexOf` version.

Comment: @Jack good investigation, and yes, release mode makes a massive difference to performance! Mainly due to bounds checking, code optimization and dropping of debug tracing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you running your timings from within Visual Studio? If so, your code would run significantly slower for that reason alone.

Aside from that, you are, to some degree, comparing apples and oranges. The two algorithms work in a different way.

The `IndexOf` version alternates between looking for an opening bracket *only* and a closing bracket *only*. Your code goes through the whole string and keeps a status flag that indicates whether it is looking for an opening or a closing bracket. This takes more work and is expected to be slower.

Here's some code that does the comparison the same way as your `IndexOf` method.

```
int match3 = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < html.Length; j++) {
    if (html[j] == '<') {
        for (; j < html.Length; j++)
            if (html[j] == '>')
                match3++;
    }
}
```

In my tests this is actually about 3 times faster than the `IndexOf` method. The reason? Strings are actually not quite as simple as sequences of individual characters. There are markers, accents, etc. `String.IndexOf` handles all that extra complexity properly, but it comes at a cost.

Comment: credit goes to you because you mentioned `Are you running your timings from within Visual Studio?`

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that comes to my mind is actual implementation of `IndexOf` iniside string class, that call

```
callvirt    System.String.IndexOf
```

which, if we use a power of reflector (as much as it possible) ends up into the

```
CompareInfo.IndexOf(..)
```

call, which instead use super fast windows native function [FindNLSString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318056%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit of a fallacy to directly compare your managed implementation and the `String.IndexOf` method.  The implementation of `IndexOf` is largely native code and hence has a different set of performance characteristics than your managed implementation.  In particular native code avoid the type safety checks, and their corresponding overhead, which injected by the CLR in the managed algorithm.

One example is the use of the array index

```
char c = html[j];
```

In managed code this statement will both verify that `j` is a valid index into the array `html` and then return the value.  The native code equivalent simply returns a memory offset with no additional checking necessary.  This lack of a check gives native code an inherent advantage here because it can avoid an additional branch instruction on every iteration of the loop.

Note that this advantage is not absolute.  The JIT could very well examine this loop and decide that `j` could never be an invalid index and elide the checks in the generated native code (and it does do this in some cases IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

I would expect `string.IndexOf` compared to your first code sample to run at least twice as fast (besides any other optimizations that might be done there) since you check for *both* start and end character in each of your iterations. Your implementation with `string.IndexOf` on the other hand will check for the end character only after it has successfully found a start character. This cuts the number of operations on each iteration down significantly (one less comparison).

Comment: Actually the `IndexOf` also check twice.

Comment: @Jack: No it doesn't: you pass the index of the found start character  `<` to `string.IndexOf` - so you are looking for the first occurrence of the end character only after that index within your input string

Comment: You mean if I find < is at 10, then my searching for > will start from 10, right? I think it is the same in my first implementation, which is also running for one go.

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean. you mean the `if` parts. I will modify my code and run again now.

Comment: for your last paragraph, I don't think `IndexOf` can quit earlier, as the last string in the whole string is </html>, i.e., `IndexOf` still need to finish scanning all the chars

Comment: @Jack: you are correct, didn't take your outer while loop into account

Comment: Please have a look at my edit. Now I even don't scan for pairs. Just to count how many `<` in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Using a switch statement instead of an if test speeds things up a little also.  This code occasionally beats the indexof code on my machine.

```
        int count = 0;
        bool open = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < testStr.Length; j++)
        {  
            switch (testStr[j])
            {
                case '<':
                    open = true;
                    break;
                case '>':
                    if (open)
                       count++;

                    open = false;
                    break;         
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you have a lot of comparisons building a hash table will speed things up